# O que tem de errado no meu código python?

Tags: python, áudio

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para filmar o desktop com o audio do sistema e do microfone.Inicialmente parecia simples mas acabei encontrando um problema no caminho:Não estou conseguindo gravar o som do sistema.Inicialmente pensei que poderia ser meu computador que estava com problemas.Mas após baixar o Camtasia consegui gravar o som do sistema e do microfone.
Havia feito uma pergunta similar a essa e um user respondeu mas o código dele não funciona dentro do meu projeto curiosamente.Então a única possibilidade é que algo esteja matando a gravação do audio do sistema.
Vou deixar aqui o código dele e o meu projeto aqui para vocês tentarem ver o que poderia ser.

**Código que o user postou(consegui pegar o audio do stereo mixer e do microfone com ele mas não funciona dentro do meu projeto):**

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np


CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 2
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp.wav"


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])


#stream usando o as_loopback para pegar som do SO
stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = 2,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    input_device_index=2,
    as_loopback=True)

##stream usando o iput device do meu Microphone
stream2 = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = 1,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    input_device_index=1)
    #as_loopback=False)


frames = []
frames2 = []


for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data2 = stream2.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
    frames2.append(data2)


#frames = dados do som as_loopback (Speakers)
frames= b''.join(frames);

#frames2 = dados do som  Microfone
frames2= b''.join(frames2);

#decodificando os dados do Speaker
Sdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames, 'int16')

#decodificando o microfone
Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames2, 'int16')

#convertendo os dados do Speaker em um vetor do tipo Numpy (facilitando a vida na hora de pegar os canais de áudio)
Sdecoded= np.array(Sdecoded, dtype='int16') 

#pegando os dados do lado direito
direito=Sdecoded[1::2]

#pegando os dados do lado esquerdo
esquerdo=Sdecoded[::2]

#mixando tudo para mono = somar lado direito + lado esquerdo + os dados decofificados do Microfone q já estão em mono
mix=(direito+esquerdo+Mdecoded)

#garantindo que nenhum valor extrapole os limites do short int
signal=np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)

#codificar os dados novamente 
encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh"%(len(signal)), *list(signal))


#parar todos os streams e finalizar o pyaudio
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
stream2.stop_stream()
stream2.close()
p.terminate()


#gravando o áudio mixado em mono 
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes((encodecoded))
wf.close()
```

**O código que fiz misturando o meu com o dele:**

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess
#from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
#CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp/tmp.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])


class recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.going = False
        self.process = None
        self.filename = "ScreenCapture.mpg"

    def record(self, filename):
        try:
            if self.process.is_alive():
                self.going = False
        except AttributeError:
            print("test")
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        self.process.start()
        self.filename = filename

    def _record(self):
        #p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=2,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=2,
            as_loopback=True)
        stream2 = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=1,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=1)
        # as_loopback=False)

        print("* recording")

        frames = []
        frames2= []

        self.going = True

        while self.going:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            data2 = stream2.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)
            frames2.append(data)
        # frames = dados do som as_loopback (Speakers)
        frames = b''.join(frames);

        # frames2 = dados do som  Microfone
        frames2 = b''.join(frames2);

        # decodificando os dados do Speaker
        Sdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames, 'int16')

        # decodificando o microfone
        Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames2, 'int16')

        # convertendo os dados do Speaker em um vetor do tipo Numpy (facilitando a vida na hora de pegar os canais de áudio)
        Sdecoded = np.array(Sdecoded, dtype='int16')

        # pegando os dados do lado direito
        direito = Sdecoded[1::2]

        # pegando os dados do lado esquerdo
        esquerdo = Sdecoded[::2]

        # mixando tudo para mono = somar lado direito + lado esquerdo + os dados decofificados do Microfone q já estão em mono
        mix = (direito + esquerdo + Mdecoded)

        # garantindo que nenhum valor extrapole os limites do short int
        signal = np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)

        # codificar os dados novamente
        encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh" % (len(signal)), *list(signal))

        print("* done recording")

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        stream2.stop_stream()
        stream2.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        #wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.writeframes((encodecoded))
        wf.close()

    def stop_recording(self):
        self.going = False
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não retorna nenhum erro? tenta mudar:`WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp.wav"` para `WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp.wave"`

Comment: Bom dia Marcos.Pior que não retorna nenhum erro.Vou tentar mudar isso.

Comment: Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.Reparei que apareceu um erro e coloquei na descrição da pergunta porque aqui ultrapassou o máximo de caracteres.

Comment: nesse mix = ... vc esta tentando somar os valores, mas ocorre o erro , pois o numpy tenta fazer um broadcasting ja que soma de arrays de dimensões diferentes e ele não está conseguindo, sugiro testar sem o mix...

Comment: Já resolvi o problema.Não era esse exatamente o problema.Mas como você foi o único que tentou me ajudar vou te dar a melhor resposta.

Comment: qual era o problema exatamente?

Comment: Não sei tbm.O importante é que funcionou.Acho que apaguei um modulo que era pra importar sem querer.